# Is it possible to fire up a pop up like windows from a UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

How can I make a UIWebView's html/javascript to trigger a UIModalView to show up on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following delegates to catch a page before it loads:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

You can check the URL that is being loaded with:

```
[[[webView request] URL] absoluteString];
```

Then create and show your UIModalView.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that is possible....